# How to consolidate JSON records from multiple files using jq

Tags: json, jq

I have a list of file names as shell variable and their contents like below

```
file_names=('one.json' 'two.json')
```

one.json:

```
{
      "key":"k1",
      "host": "..",
      "name": ".."    
}
```

two.json:

```
{
      "key":"k2",
      "host": "..",
      "name": ".."
}
```

I want to create a consolidate file with all the contents from the above files. There can be more than 2 files. In the consolidate file the `key` value will become the outer level key of the JSON record. eg:

```
{
    "k1": {
      "host": "..",
      "name": ".."   
    },
    "k2": {
      "host": "..",
      "name": ".."   
    }
}
```

How can I achieve this using jq ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`INDEX`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#SQL-StyleOperators):

```
jq -n 'INDEX(inputs; .key) | map_values(del(.key))' "${file_names[@]}"
```